# VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of (Constructor) in (Class)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, robotlegs

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 and I've come across a bizarre issue, without any changes to the class this is occurring in I get:

```
VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of HUDScreen in mobile_ui.screens.HUDScreen.
```

This class extends Sprite, and implements an interface.  As far as I know, all methods in the interface have the proper prototypes.  There are no overridden properties or functions in this class.  We are using robotlegs for dependency injection as well, if that is relevant.

Class Definition

```
public class HUDScreen extends Sprite implements IHUDScreen
{
}
```

Constructor

```
public function HUDScreen()
{

}
```

Interface Definition

```
public interface IHUDScreen extends IEventDispatcher
{

}
```

I've tried cleaning the project, I've deleted and re-imported the project, I've changed the package from ui.screens.HUDScreen to mobile_ui.screens.HUDScreen.  Nothing changed the error.

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated at this point!

Thank you for your time.

Edit: I've added the class definition, interface definition, and constructor.

UPDATE: I've been able to move past this problem, I've outlined what I did in my answer below.  I'm still interested in anyone's thoughts or ideas on how this could have happened, or perhaps a more concrete solution.

Thanks again to everyone who took the time to view this question!

Comment: We need to see code to help. At the very least, we need to see the class definition as well as the HUDScreen method definition.

Comment: I've added the things you've asked for, I'm not sure if they'll shed much light on the situation.  I can't really post more, as it's a rather large class and it is private code.  Hopefully this gives you something to work with.  Thanks you for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: Did you try building with earlier versions of Flash Builder, or with earlier FP compatibility?

Comment: I don't have access to earlier versions of FB.  This is an AIR project, it is being built to the earliest swf version the AIR SDK supports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is caused by an incorrect implementation of an interface that the compiler doesn't detect. The following code snipped causes the error:

```
public class Foo implements IFoo
{
    public function bar():String { return ""; }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    function get bar():String;
}
```

The problem is caused by the fact that `IFoo.bar` is a getter, but `Foo.bar()` is a normal method. This is a kind of error that could be easily missed when looking through your code, and that would be fixed if you delete and rewrite everything.

Comment: This is the answer that actually helped me. I had functions that were getters in the class but should not have been accorrding to the interface that class implemented.

Comment: I'm setting this as the accepted answer as it's quite a bit more constructive than my own answer.  I have not run into this issue again.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why this happened or how.  However, I was able to get it working again.

My idea was to remove all the methods from the class, and add stubs for all the methods in the interface.  Then, add the actual methods back one-by-one until I could see possibly where the issue was occurring.

Bizarrely, after restoring the methods one at a time, and testing each time, it now works.

The class is (essentially, code is probably laid out slightly differently) the same, and now it works.

I'm still boggled, but at the very least I can move on for now.

Hopefully, this can help somebody somewhere.

Comment: I had this error because stageSync or stageObserver extension. dont recall

Comment: I believe we are using one of those, I'll look into it if this issue pops up again. Thanks for the suggestion!